# Module not found, can't resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, webpack

I am having an error on React, I have a class component called movie and I am getting module not found, so React in webpack can't compile, despite having the component on the right path.

Here is the component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class Movie extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div onClick={this.props.deleteMethod}>
                {this.props.text}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Movie;
```

Here is the import (where component is expected but not found):
(in : ./src/components/AddComponent.jsx)

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Movie from './component/Movie.jsx';


class AddComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            movieText: '',
            movies: [],
        };
    }

updateMovieText(movieText){
    this.setState({movieText: movieText.target.value})
}

addMovie(){
    if(this.state.movieText === ''){return}

    let moviesArr = this.state.movies;
    moviesArr.push(this.state.movieText);
    this.setState({movieText: ''})
    this.textInput.focus();
}

handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){

    }
}

deleteMovie(index) {
    let movieArr = this.state.movies;
    movieArr.splice(index,1);//remove the movie from array
    this.setState({movies: movieArr})
}


    render(){
        let movie = this.state.movie.map((val,key)=> {
            return <Movie key={key} text={val} deleteMethod={() => this.deleteMovie(key)} />
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text"
                    ref={((input)=>{this.textInput = input;})}
                    value={this.state.movieText}
                    onChangeText={movieText => this.updateMovieText(movieText)}
                    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
                    />
                <button onClick={this.addMovie.bind(this)}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddComponent;
```

Comment: Should be `import Movie from './Movie.jsx';` not `import Movie from './component/Movie.jsx';`  in your */src/components/AddComponent.jsx* IMHO

Comment: Paths are relative to the component doing the import. Also, you have `component`and `components`in the path.

Comment: @rodrigoap What do you mean when you say that I have component and components in the path?

Answer (score 2):

You have defined the path wrong. In AddComponent you are already at the directory you want, so is just:

```
import Movie from './Movie.jsx';
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an "s" in component at `import Movie from './component/Movie.jsx` ?